# Vaadin - TypeError: window.Vaadin.Flow.clients[j] is undefined

Tags: grid, components, vaadin, selector, vaadin-flow

I get an error when I add this code to a grid component:

```
new ComponentRenderer<>(Button::new, (button, plotno) -> {
                    button.setIcon(new Icon(VaadinIcon.TRASH));
                    button.addClickListener(e -> {
                        this.usunPlotno(plotno);
                    });
```

What is wrong here?

In context, it looks like (within a constructor of a class that extends `Grid`):

```
        addColumn(Material::getId).setHeader("Lp: ");
        addColumn(Material::getWysokoscCm).setHeader("Wysokość: ");
        addColumn(Material::getCenaZl).setHeader("Cena: ");
        addColumn(
                new ComponentRenderer<>(Button::new, (button, plotno) -> {
                    // button.setText("usun");
                    button.setIcon(new Icon(VaadinIcon.TRASH));
                    button.addClickListener(e -> {
                        this.usunPlotno(plotno);
                        Notification.show("material clicked");
                    });
                })
                ).setHeader("Usuń:");
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend something like the following (note I do not know exactly where the `plotno` comes, so I just guessed you have `getPlotno` in your `Material` bean for it. The main point here is that you I think use component renderer wrong way.

```
new ComponentRenderer<>(material -> {
                    Button button = new Button("usun")
                    button.setIcon(new Icon(VaadinIcon.TRASH));
                    button.addClickListener(e -> {
                        this.usunPlotno(material.getPlotno());
                    return button;
                });
```